# Which of these functions can I disable in PHP.ini? What does Magento2 use?

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm attempting to lock down my server and I'd like to disable some high risk functions (listed below).

Would someone be able to definitively tell me which ones Magento 2.1.* needs to work correctly so I can disable the rest?

system, exec, shell_exec, passthru, phpinfo, show_source, popen, proc_open, fopen_with_path, dbmopen, dbase_open, putenv, move_uploaded_file, chdir, mkdir, rmdir, chmod, rename, filepro, filepro_rowcount, filepro_retrieve, posix_mkfifo, ini_set